# Setting the value of a dropdown in django view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates, jinja2

I have a HTML dropdown,When I select some value,it navigates to a different HTML page containing another dropdown.I want to set the dropdown in new page with the previous dropdown value.How can I accomplish this in views.py?
HTML template

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="exampleFormControlSelect1" >
          
            <option value="val">key</option>
          
        </select>
```

views.py

```
def getListValues(request,num):
    
    year_dropdown=request.POST.get('exampleFormControlSelect1')
    t1=request.POST.get('exampleFormControlSelect2')
    
    t2=t1.replace("'","")
    #print("The value is" ,t2)
    val=getData(t2)
    #print("data is:",val)
    return render(request,'home/welcome.html',{"Names":getTitles(),"Details":val})
```

urls.py

```
path('home/page<int:num>',views.getListValues,name='listvals'),
```

Now,I want to update the dropdown value from the value I have in view

Comment: You can pass a sender value to the next page, let's say if the first option in your dropdown menu is clicked pass the value "1" via url, then you can set the dropdown based on the sender value received from previous selection.

Comment: could you quote an example?

Comment: Well you should share your view,html and url structure first. But I'm also pretty sure you can find a solid answer on what you are looking for by doing a quick search.

Comment: @mattarello Please take a look at the updated question

Comment: do you redirect by js?

Comment: @mattarello how can I use js when my data is in view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217096/discussion-between-sri-test-and-mattarello).